# Disable Radio groups for certain period of time (Android)

Tags: android, android-radiogroup

I have 3 Radio Groups in a custom list view.
I need to enable the first radio group from morning 9 to 1 pm and disable after that. Second radio group to be enable from 1 pm to 8 pm and disable after and third radio group to be enabled from 8 pm to 8 am and disable after. How can I achieve the same ??

BroadCastReceiver.java

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {
private static BroadcastReceiver mTickReceiver;

public BackgroundService()
{

}



@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    registerReceiver();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    unregisterReceiver(mTickReceiver);
    mTickReceiver = null;
}



private void registerReceiver()
{
    mTickReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)  // this will fire every minute
        {
            String shift = null;
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            String currentTimeString = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            Log.d("CurrentTime",currentTimeString);
            int currentTime=convertTimeToMinutes(currentTimeString);
            Log.d("CurrentTime1", String.valueOf(currentTime));
            Intent i=new Intent();
            i.setAction("TimeData");

            if(currentTime>=480 && currentTime<780) {
                shift = "Shift1";

            }
           else if(currentTime>=780 && currentTime<1200) {
                shift = "Shift2";


            }
           else if(currentTime>=1200 || currentTime<480) {
                shift = "Shift3";

            }
            Log.d("TAG1",shift);

            intent.putExtra("Shift",shift);

            sendBroadcast(i);


        }
    };
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK); // this will broadcast Intent every minute
    registerReceiver(mTickReceiver, filter);
}
private int convertTimeToMinutes(String s) {
    String[] hourMin = s.split(":");
    int hour = Integer.parseInt(hourMin[0]);
    int mins = Integer.parseInt(hourMin[1]);
    int hoursInMins = hour * 60;
    return hoursInMins + mins;
}
```

}

In Activity onCreate method I am calling BroadcastReceiver as following

```
    Intent i=new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class);
    startService(i);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("TimeData");
    registerReceiver(new MyBroadcastReceiver(),filter);
```

BroadCastReceiver Class in Activity is as follows

```
    class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // GET BROADCAST FROM RECEIVER IN THE BACKGROUND SERVICE CLASS
        Toast.makeText(context, "Action: " + intent.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Log.d("ActionData",intent.getAction());  // this works, it is checked

        if (intent.getAction() == "TimeData") {
            String shiftValue1= intent.getStringExtra("Shift");
            Log.d("shiftValue1",shiftValue1);
        }
    }
}
```

Error I am getting is

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                       Process: com.rakyow.ehandor, PID: 11492
>                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=TimeData flg=0x10 } in com.rakyow.ehandor.HandoverDetailActivity$MyBroadcastReceiver@1acc203e
>                                                                           at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:917)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
>                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
>                                                                           at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
>                                                                           at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:139)
>                                                                           at com.rakyow.ehandor.HandoverDetailActivity$MyBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(HandoverDetailActivity.java:290)
>                                                                           at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:907)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576) 
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956) 
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)

Comment: Use service that checks current time using ACTION_TICK filter, if current time is your desired time, send broadcast to update UI.

Comment: @Talha I am a beginner in android..Can you please help with me some examples??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how you check time every minute:

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {
    private static BroadcastReceiver mTickReceiver;

    public BackgroundService()
    {

    }



    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        registerReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        unregisterReceiver(mTickReceiver);
        mTickReceiver = null;
    }



    private void registerReceiver()
    {
        mTickReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)  // this will fire every minute
            {
                Log.d("TAG", "TICKS");
                // Check current time using getTimeInMilliSeconds() 
               // if time is in your desired range, send UI an intent that it should change radio buttons 

            }
        };
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK); // this will broadcast Intent every minute
        registerReceiver(mTickReceiver, filter);
    }

}
```

[***How to send info/data from a receiver in a service to MainActivity***](https://gist.github.com/talhahasanzia/c2edde310ab8ad4e1fd222c9aee98680), in your case info to update UI.

In above example I passed location data, you can pass any information once you checked your time range.

**UPDATE:**

- Use `SimpleDateFormat` to convert milliseconds to hours string (e.g. 1481879288 is "09:08am" (gmt)).
- Write a function that convert HH:mm [am/pm] format into minutes - "09:08am" into 728 minutes, or say "02:35pm" to 875 minutes, this is from 12:00am reference point where 12:00am is 0 minutes elapsed. `(Hint: break string, convert hours to minutes, add minutes part to converted one, write checks for am/pm)` *Hint for hint - if you convert milliseconds to 24-hour format, you will avoid check for am/pm, simply multiply 60xhourPart and add minutes part.*
- Compare minutes range with your range e.g. from 08:00am to 08:00pm, it will be 480 minutes to 1200 minutes, so if current time is 09:08am the check will be :

  ```
   int currentTime=convertTimeToMinutes(currentTimeString);              

   // to check if time is between 08:00am to 08:00pm

   if(currentTime>=480 && currentTime<=1200) {

      Log.d(TAG,"Current time is in between 08:00am to 08:00pm");

  }
  ```

> How if the range is between 8pm-8am(Next day happens)??

If that's the case, use check to see if time is greater than 8pm or it is lower than 8am , notice here check is || not &&.

```
if (currentTime>=1320 || currentTime <=480)
{
// your stuff
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

`String` comparison must always be with `.equals()` method not `==`, since you use `==`, the line

`String shiftValue1= intent.getStringExtra("Shift")`

never executes, you should write it as :

```
if (intent.getAction().equals("TimeData")) {
            String shiftValue1= intent.getStringExtra("Shift");
            Log.d("shiftValue1",shiftValue1);
}
```

**UPDATE 3**

dont do this:

```
intent.putExtra("Shift",shift);
```

do this:

```
i.putExtra("Shift",shift);
```

See you are sending same intent object that was received.

Comment: @Talha..thanks for the help..But how can I check the current time with my desired time(For eg: 8 am )in milliseconds or so?

Comment: How if the range is between 8pm-8am(Next day happens)??

Comment: Between I am getting null pointer exception on Broadcast receiver when I try to log the received value. My code is class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction() == "TimeData") {
                String shiftValue1= intent.getStringExtra("Shift");
                Log.d("shiftValue1",shiftValue1);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: add code to question and update, also post code where you register receiver with intent.

Comment: At which line exactly it throw NPE? the code seems to have no issue.

Comment: Throws exception on  Log.d("shiftValue1",shiftValue1);

Comment: Sorry there is no function intent.putStringExtra()...Only intent.putExtra()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130927/discussion-between-amit-nair-and-talha).

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of functionality you can either **create timer service** which checks the time for particular time periods or you can use the **alarm service** which will be triggered at particular time.